# In $\lim(x,y)\to(0,0)$ why can I change to $(x^2,x)$?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

When we have a multivariable function  and we want to see if the function is continuous at a point, normally the origin, we sometimes "change" $(x,y)\to(0,0)$ to expressions like $(x^2,x)\to(0,0)$ to make it work.

For example, for the function:
$f(x)=\begin{cases}\frac{yx^2}{(x^4+y^2)}&  \text{if } (x,y)\neq (0,0)\\
0& \text{if } (x,y)=(0,0)\end{cases}$

In order to see the discontinuity we can consider $(x,xm)\to(0,0)$ and we get $0$. But if we change to $(x,x^2)\to(0,0)$, the limit becomes $1/2$.

Why can we choose those curves?

Also, for a different function, could I choose $(1/x,x)\to(0,0)$. I know the limit of $1/x$ as $x$ goes to zero does not exist, therefore I am unsure.

Comment: $(1/x,x) \not \to (0,0).$

Comment: We need to choose $(f(t),g(t))$ such that $f(t)$ and $g(t)$ each has limit $0$.

Comment: If the limit at $(0,0)$ exists, it is the same when the function is restricted to a set that still has $(0,0)$ as a limit point. So that trick allows you to state the limit doesn't exist, because two restrictions of the function have different limits.

Comment: The real answer to your question (Why do we choose those curves?) is that those curves are one for which we can show that the limit doesn't exist.  My advice is to look at at plot of what $yx^2 /(x^4+y^2)$ looks like on some computer algebra system.  It actually is quite interesting at the origin.  I think that looking at the graphs are the best way to build intuition.

Comment: If any of the answeres below were usefull to you, then you should [upvote](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) them and [accept](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) the one that was most useful to you. If answers are not useful to you, then it helps if you say why not. This helps others to help you.

Answer (score 4):

Confronted with such a problem you have to make a decision, founded on your experience with similar problems: Shall I try to prove that the limit exists, or shall I try to prove that the limit does not exist?

If you conjecture that the limit $\lim_{{\bf z}\to{\bf 0}}f({\bf z})$ *does not exist* you can try to exhibit two curves $$\gamma:\quad t\mapsto{\bf z}(t)=\bigl(x(t),y(t)\bigr)\ne{\bf 0},\qquad \lim_{t\to0+}{\bf z}(t)={\bf 0}\ ,\tag{1}$$
for which the limit  $\lim_{t\to0+}f\bigl({\bf z}(t)\bigr)$ is different, or one such curve, for which this limit does not exist. The logic behind this procedure is as follows: If  $\lim_{{\bf z}\to{\bf 0}}f({\bf z})=\alpha$ for a certain $\alpha$ then by the "law of nested limits" one has $\lim_{t\to0+}f\bigl({\bf z}(t)\bigr)=\alpha$ for all curves $(1)$.

If you conjecture that the limit $\lim_{{\bf z}\to{\bf 0}}f({\bf z})$ *exists* then you have to provide a fulfledged $\epsilon/\delta$ proof of this conjecture, and you cannot resort to special curves for a proof. In such cases it often, but not always, helps to express $f$ in polar coordinates, because the variable $r$ encodes the nearness of ${\bf z}$ to ${\bf 0}$ in a particularly simple way.

Comment: Yes, but the question is why can I choose any curves and put them in the limit. Why is that operation allowed?

Answer (score 2):

I think I know how to make this clear.

Consider for example the function of one variable $g(x)=\begin{cases}1&x>0\\-1&x<0\end{cases}$

[image: Graph of $g(x)$]

How would you show that $\lim\limits_ {x\to 0}g(x)$ does not exist? Well, you say that $\underbrace{\lim\limits_{x\downarrow 0}g(x)=1}_{\text{the limit from the right}}$ and $\underbrace{\lim\limits_{x\uparrow 0}g(x)=-1}_{\text{the limit from the left}}$. If the limit exists these should be equal.

Why does it make sense to consider  this?
If we say that $\lim\limits _{x\to a}g(x)=L$ then this means that $g(x)$ gets increasingly close to $L$, if $x$ approaches $a$. **No matter how $x$ approaches $a$.** The "*no matter how*" part is really important. It would make very little sense to say that $\lim g(x) =1$, if this is not true when we approach from the left.

Now, in the one-variable case  it is enough to check only the left-hand limit and the right-hand limit. Why? Well because $x$ can only approach $a$ in two ways:

- in a straight line form the right
- in a straight line from the left.

So in this case **no matter how $x$ approaches $a$** is the same as saying **no matter if $x$ approaches $a$ from the left or right**.

---

Now for functions of more than one variable (for instance: two), not much changes. If we say that $\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}f(x,y)=L$, we want this to be true **no matter how $(x,y)$ approaches $(0,0)$**. The big difference is that there are now more than two ways for $(x,y)$ to approach $(0,0)$, or any other point. In fact there are infinitely many ways.

Beacause there are infinitely many ways for $(x,y)$ to approach a point, this will not help you to actually find a limit. However, it can be usefull to show that a limit does not exist. For suppose that we find  there are (at least) two different ways to approach a point that give different outcomes. In that case we could no longer say that $f(x,y)$ gets close to $L$, **no matter how...** We have in stead shown that it does matter, thus the limit can't exist.

---

In your example you **may** choose to approach $(0,0)$ along the paths $(x,mx)$ and $(x,x^2)$, because these are paths along which we can actually approach $(0,0)$. But we may just as well have chosen any other way to approach $(0,0)$.  These particular paths are **usefull**, because they give you different outcomes, immediately implying that the limit does not exist.

You cannot actually approach $(0,0)$ along the path $(1/x,x)$, so this is not right.